# How to Convert string-> pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

i'm working with web services that returns a base64 string representing a pdf file.

I am able to decode that string into NSData but how to show that into pdf.

Is there any way to store that data as a .pdf file and show it in application.

Any ideas on how I can go about this? I have looked at a few posts and still can't seem to figure it out.

Any idea's appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to save the data into a file, then load it into a webview

```
 - (void)DisplayPdf:(NSData *)pdfContent
{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPdf.pdf"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
        [pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];

        [aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: this is working I am able to save the file as .pdf but when I open it in webview I get only blank pdf. But in background I mean at Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/ I able to get pdf correctly what is the problem do you hav any idea?

Comment: Just to cover the bases - if you load any other url in the webview - is it displayed correctly?

Comment: yes it correctly opens the url..... i dont understand that while displaying pdf why webview showing blank? i think while storing pdf or while creating url of that pdf there might be wrong somthing dont know exactly....

Comment: The result is a UIWebView that displays a blank page. No errors occur in the UIWebView delegate method. The thing is that data has the correct length, in bytes, for the PDF I am trying to display, and I also get the pdf file in Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/ 

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going wrong here or how I can better debug this problem?

Comment: You might want to implement the `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` and `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` to see what's wrong. Also, although, afaik, the writeToUrl method should be synchronous it might not be so and the webview will actually start loading the pdf file before it gets a chance to be filled?